# Move out of a Mutex in a static element

Tags: rust, mutex

I have this static element:

```
pub static CREDENTIALS: Mutex<DatabaseCredentials> = Mutex::new(DatabaseCredentials::new());
```

and I want to take the content out of the `Mutex`:

```
let creds = CREDENTIALS.into_inner().unwrap().clone();
```

and I am getting this error:

```
let creds = CREDENTIALS.into_inner().unwrap();
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `CREDENTIALS` has type `std::sync::Mutex<connection::credentials::DatabaseCredentials<'_>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Where my `DatabaseCredentials` looks as follows:

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
pub struct DatabaseCredentials<'a> {
    pub username: &'a str,
    pub password: &'a str,
    pub host: &'a str,
    pub db_name: &'a str
}

unsafe impl Send for DatabaseCredentials<'_> {}
unsafe impl Sync for DatabaseCredentials<'_> {}

// impl block...
```

How can I get rid out of the error, and take the underlying value inside the `Mutex`?

Comment: `clone` first and then move out of it instead of the other way around?

Comment: What do you want to do if someone accesses the data after?

Comment: @isaacta can't clone an `std::sync::Mutex`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I would prefer to not take the value, and just pass a reference to another method. But that method is send across threads, so I would have to impl `Send + Sync` with the new type pattern for `std::sync::Mutex`? That's w'd be an option?

Comment: Send and Sync are automatically added. You can't implement them yourself.

Comment: @mousetail ?? We are in a static context, so I can't wrap the `Mutex` with an `Arc`.
Specifically: `cannot call non-const fn `Arc::<Mutex<DatabaseCredentials>>::new` in statics
calls in statics are limited to constant functions, tuple structs and tuple variants`

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to move the data or not?

Comment: @mousetail You can't move out of `Arc`, so this won't help.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman yes. Forget about the rest

Comment: @mousetail no. They not automatically added: future cannot be sent between threads safely
within `impl Future<Output = Result<DatabaseResult<T>, tokio_postgres::Error>>`, the trait `Send` is not implemented for `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, connection::credentials::DatabaseCredentials<'_>>`
required for the cast to the object type `dyn Future<Output = Result<DatabaseResult<T>, tokio_postgres::Error>> + Send`

Comment: @AlexVergara My point is they can not be added manually. They either exist or do not.

Comment: @mousetail checkout the `new type pattern`. That could be a nice point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I get rid out of the error, and take the underlying value inside the Mutex?

I would suggest reworking your system so you don't have to, because it's odd, why would you have a mutex and want to move things out of it rather than just use the protected object in-place?

But if you really need to, given your mutex is static you have three options:

1. `Copy` or `Clone` the stored `DatabaseCredentials`, no need to `into_inner` anything, just deref' the `MutexGuard`. That will create an owned copy of the credentials.
2. Add an indirection through an `Option`, this way you can [`Option::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take) the `DatabaseCredentials` out of the `Mutex`. This will leave the mutex valid but containing a `None`.
3. [`std::mem::replace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.replace.html) the contents of the mutex by a newly created `DatabaseCredentials`, you'll get the one which was stored in the mutex.

In all three cases, you have to lock the mutex first.

Comment: Even those 3 are valid, first one adresses the question perfectly fine. Thanks